# can we "fight" against "an issue" and a "social tension"

Tags: expressions

> We should fight against these issues.

and

> We should fight against these social tensions.

are they correct?

Comment: What makes you doubt your choices?

Comment: One typically *addresses* issues and *resolves* tensions. Using martial metaphor here feels off.

Comment: What are  "social tensions"?

Comment: @JMB well actually I would go with both of them, I was wondering which one sound the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these strike me as very casual uses of the words in play: the sort of thing people say when they're content to say something in the general neighborhood of what they mean without stopping to think about what they are saying.

In casual speech, for instance, *issues* has recently come to mean basically the same thing as *problems*—"I have issues with that". But in formal discourse an *issue* is either a point of disagreement or the disagreement itself. It makes little sense to speak of *fighting* a disagreement. One may fight for one side or the other, or fight to resolve the disagreement, but I don't see how you can *fight against* the disagreement itself.

*Tensions*, whether social or political or economic or personal, are in much the same case. No doubt we all want to *reduce* tensions, or *resolve* them, or *minimize* them; but it's hard to see how this might be accomplished by *fighting against* the tensions themselves, which would on the contrary seem to be a pretty tension-inducing activity!

Comment: Notwithstanding inane Bush-speak _War on Terror_!

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock was it a code?

Comment: @StoneyB I understood the rule (or the usage) but I still find weird we could "fight against poverty" but not against a "social tension/issue" since poverty **is** a social tension/issue...

Comment: @GuillaumeCombot Not really. Poverty causes social tension, and it is an 'issue' only in the sense that it is the subject of much argument.